# Есть ли форма множественного числа у существительного "знать"?

Tags: грамматика

Образовать множественное число несложно, но является ли такая форма литературной?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если "знать" - собирательное существительное, то такие существительные не имеют формы множественного числа (студенчество, крестьянство).